# Wrong formatting with numprint package and nprounddigits

Tags: formatting, numprint

I'm using the `numprint` package to format my numbers, some of them which are rounded with `\nprounddigits`, but sometimes the formatting is wrong, like if it was somehow done before rounding, ie `\nprounddigits{0}\numprint{99999.99}\npnoround{}` gives me 10 000 0 instead of 100 000.

These are the packages used in my TeX file :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, onecolumn]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

and the part where the bug lies :

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering}m{2cm}|X|}
\hline
Taux & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Palier}\\
\hline
\nprounddigits{2}1\npnoround{}\,\% & De \nprounddigits{0}\numprint{50000}\npnoround{}~\euro{} à \nprounddigits{0}\numprint{99999.99}\npnoround{}~\euro{}\\
\nprounddigits{2}1.5\npnoround{}\,\% & De \nprounddigits{0}\numprint{100000}\npnoround{}~\euro{} à \nprounddigits{0}\numprint{149999.99}\npnoround{}~\euro{}\\
\nprounddigits{2}2\npnoround{}\,\% & De \nprounddigits{0}\numprint{150000}\npnoround{}~\euro{} à \nprounddigits{0}\numprint{199999.99}\npnoround{}~\euro{}\\
\nprounddigits{2}2.5\npnoround{}\,\% & À partir de \nprounddigits{0}\numprint{200000}\npnoround{}~\euro{}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

This is really strange as on the next line, `\nprounddigits{0}\numprint{149999.99}\npnoround{}` gives me 150 000 as it should.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: It's a very tricky issue. The rounding adds a new position. A simple solution is `\numprint{099999.99}` (adding a `0`)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Certainly one has to watch these things :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Indeed, this is a valable workaround, implying you already now hom many digits will be in the rounded number. Seems like `numprint` handles numbers more like strings than real numbers.  @MartinSchröder Thanks for the welcome !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in `numprint`. I suggest that you use `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, onecolumn]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[round-mode=places,locale=FR]{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering}m{2cm}|X|}
\hline
Taux & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Palier}\\
\hline
\num[round-precision=2]{1}\% &
  De \num[round-precision=0]{50000}~\euro{} à
  \num[round-precision=0]{99999.99}~\euro{}\\
\num[round-precision=2]{1.5}\% &
  De \num[round-precision=0]{100000}~\euro{} à
  \num[round-precision=0]{149999.99}~\euro{}\\
\num[round-precision=2]{2}\% &
  De \num[round-precision=0]{150000}~\euro{} à
  \num[round-precision=0]{199999.99}~\euro{}\\
\num[round-precision=2]{2.5}\% & 
  À partir de \num[round-precision=0]{200000}~\euro{}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought I'll use `numprint` because I only needed number rounding and formatting (damn minimalism !) but it looks like `siunitx` is better and more complete. Thanks for the suggestion, it will perfectly suit my needs.