# How Do You Use Numprint In Conjunction With Multirow?

Tags: tables, multirow, alignment, dcolumn, numprint

Try as I might, nothing so far has worked. I'm trying to align the "9:1" as a `\multirow`, but I usually just end up getting an `illegal pream-token` error. Fitting the `\multirow` inside of a `\multicolumn` gets rid of the error, but also strips the formatting from the cell. This is what I want it to look like:

[image: Desired Result]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
  \newcolumntype{,}{D{.}{.}{-2}}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}
\usepackage{numprint}
\npdecimalsign{.}

\begin{document}

\scriptsize \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | >{\npdecimalsign{:}}N{2}{3} | n{3}{1} | >{\centering}m{35px}  c | >{\npafternum{ \%}}n{3}{1} | >{\npafternum{ \%}}n{3}{1} | >{\npafternum{ \%}}n{3}{1} | }
 \hline
\multirow{3}{35px}{type} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{25px}{\centering item ratio}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{20px}{\centering total count}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{p{70px} |}{\multirow{2}{70px}{\scriptsize \centering expected number of each type per set}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{30px}[0.125em]{\tiny \centering probability of seeing at least one item}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{30px}[0.125em]{\tiny \centering probability of seeing duplicate items}}& 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{30px}[0.125em]{\tiny \centering probability of seeing a specific item}}\\&&&&&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-5} &&&\centering total&\centering unique&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\
\hline
Type A&1.49&3&\multicolumn{1}{,}{0}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{0}&54.5&11.1&32.3\\
Type B&1.15&8&\multicolumn{1}{,}{2}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{2}&87.6&15.9&18.2\\
Type C&1.7&15&\multicolumn{1}{,}{3}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{3}&98.7&47.6&33.2\\
Type D&1.1&19&\multicolumn{1}{,}{24}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{13}&100&100&76.7\\
\hline
Type 1&\multirow{2}{*}{9.1}&11&\multicolumn{1}{,}{15}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{9}&100&99.5&69.6\\
Type 2&&54&\multicolumn{1}{,}{170}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{51}&100&100&96.8\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Total}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{n{3}{1}}{110}&\multicolumn{1}{,}{214}&\multicolumn{1}{,}{78}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}\normalsize

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149368/wrong-formatting-with-numprint-package-and-nprounddigits?rq=1

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer if you just repeat 9:1?

Comment: I was thinking that since Type 1 and Type 2 combined make up a 9:1 ratio, that I should merge the cell to make that clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\multirow` generates a box, which can't be used as the argument for the `N{2}{3}` column specifier. What you could do is put the argument of the `\multirow` in a separate `N{2}{3}` processing (i.e. do it inside the `\multirow` rather than outside of it). I do this with the `\NP` command that I defined. You have to put the `\multirow` in braces to protect it from the `N` column processing in the main tabular, or maybe even better, put it in a `\multicolumn{1}{l}`. But just braces seem to work well. And I used `12:1` in the cell, just to show that it works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
  \newcolumntype{,}{D{.}{.}{-2}}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}
\usepackage{numprint}
\npdecimalsign{.}
\newcommand\NP[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\npdecimalsign{:}}N{2}{3}@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\scriptsize \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | >{\npdecimalsign{:}}N{2}{3} | n{3}{1} | >{\centering}m{35px}  c | >{\npafternum{ \%}}n{3}{1} | >{\npafternum{ \%}}n{3}{1} | >{\npafternum{ \%}}n{3}{1} | }
 \hline
\multirow{3}{35px}{type} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{25px}{\centering item ratio}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{20px}{\centering total count}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{p{70px} |}{\multirow{2}{70px}{\scriptsize \centering expected number of each type per set}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{30px}[0.125em]{\tiny \centering probability of seeing at least one item}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{30px}[0.125em]{\tiny \centering probability of seeing duplicate items}}& 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{30px}[0.125em]{\tiny \centering probability of seeing a specific item}}\\&&&&&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\\cline{4-5} &&&\centering total&\centering unique&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\
\hline
Type A&1.49&3&\multicolumn{1}{,}{0}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{0}&54.5&11.1&32.3\\
Type B&1.15&8&\multicolumn{1}{,}{2}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{2}&87.6&15.9&18.2\\
Type C&1.7&15&\multicolumn{1}{,}{3}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{3}&98.7&47.6&33.2\\
Type D&1.1&19&\multicolumn{1}{,}{24}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{13}&100&100&76.7\\
\hline
Type 1& {\multirow{2}{*}{\NP{12.1}}} & 11 &\multicolumn{1}{,}{15}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{9}&100&99.5&69.6\\
%Type 1&9.1&11&\multicolumn{1}{,}{15}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{9}&100&99.5&69.6\\
Type 2&&54&\multicolumn{1}{,}{170}&\multicolumn{1}{,|}{51}&100&100&96.8\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Total}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{n{3}{1}}{110}&\multicolumn{1}{,}{214}&\multicolumn{1}{,}{78}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}\normalsize

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! That works beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

With `siunitx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{ ll *{2}{S[table-format=3]} S[table-format=2] *{3}{S[table-format=3.1]}}
\toprule
{\thead{type}} & 
{\thead{item\\ ratio}} & 
{\thead{total\\ count}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{expected number of\\ each type per set}} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{probability in \% of seeing}}\\ 
\cmidrule(r){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-8}
&&& {\thead{total}} & {\thead{unique}} &
{\thead{at least\\ one item}} & 
{\thead{duplicate\\ items}}& 
{\thead{specific\\ item}}\\ 
\midrule
Type A & 1:49 & 3   & 0   & 0  & 54.5 & 11.1 & 32.3 \\
Type B & 1:15 & 8   & 2   & 2  & 87.6 & 15.9 & 18.2 \\
Type C & 1:7  & 15  & 3   & 3  & 98.7 & 47.6 & 33.2 \\
Type D & 1:1  & 19  & 24  & 13 & 100  & 100  & 76.7 \\
\midrule
Type 1 & \multirow{2}{*}{9:1}  & 11  & 15  & 9  & 100  & 99.5 & 69.6 \\
Type 2 &      & 54  & 170 & 51 & 100  & 100  & 96.8 \\
\midrule
Total  &      & 110 & 214 & 78 &                    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to change it to 12:1? How would I maintain the alignment about the colon/decimal?